# An exception is raised when parsing files containing rdf:parseType="Collection"

Tags: dotnetrdf

An exception is raised when parsing files containing rdf:parseType="Collection".

```
VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfParseException: [Line 44 Column 22] Expected an ElementEvent but encountered a 'VDS.RDF.Parsing.Events.RdfXml.TextEvent'
Occurred in Grammar Production 'PropertyElement'
[Source XML]
新編　洋樂歌謠曲選集　第二輯

   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionPropertyElement(RdfXmlParserContext context, IEventQueue`1 eventlist, IRdfXmlEvent parent)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionPropertyElementList(RdfXmlParserContext context, IEventQueue`1 eventlist, IRdfXmlEvent parent)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionNodeElement(RdfXmlParserContext context, IEventQueue`1 eventlist)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionParseTypeCollectionPropertyElement(RdfXmlParserContext context, IEventQueue`1 eventlist, IRdfXmlEvent parent)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionPropertyElement(RdfXmlParserContext context, IEventQueue`1 eventlist, IRdfXmlEvent parent)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionPropertyElementList(RdfXmlParserContext context, IEventQueue`1 eventlist, IRdfXmlEvent parent)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionNodeElement(RdfXmlParserContext context, IEventQueue`1 eventlist)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionNodeElementList(RdfXmlParserContext context, IEventQueue`1 eventlist)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.GrammarProductionRDF(RdfXmlParserContext context, ElementEvent element)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.ProcessEventQueue(RdfXmlParserContext context)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.Parse(RdfXmlParserContext context)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfXmlParser.Load(IRdfHandler handler, TextReader input, IUriFactory uriFactory)
   at VDS.RDF.Parsing.FileLoader.Load(IGraph g, String filename, IRdfReader parser)
```

The method is called as follows.

```
var g = new Graph();
FileLoader.Load(g, filePath);
```

RDF/XML sections with parsing errors.

```
    <dcterms:tableOfContents rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <dcterms:title>新編　洋樂歌謠曲選集　第二輯</dcterms:title>
    </dcterms:tableOfContents>
```

[Target File](https://ndlsearch.ndl.go.jp/en/books/R100000002-I000000659844)

(Click on 'Output Bibliographic Record' to select the DC-NDL (RDF) format for download)

No error if the literal is not included, such as `<dcterms:title></dcterms:title>`

Can the above formats be supported?
I don't need to be able to retrieve data, I just need to ignore the target element and not exit with an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the input data. The `rdf:parseType="Collection"`  attribute indicates that the content should be a collection of RDF nodes, but in the data there is only a literal property.

You can check this against the [W3C Validator Service](https://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) which also reports a fairly similar error.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
I did not know that there was a service called W3C Validator Service.

Comment: When we contacted the provider of the RDF files, they replied that they were aware that the file format was incorrect and that they would fix the files they provide.
Therefore, there appears to be no need to modify the library.